# Building velo query function to sum total values from multiple datasets

Tags: javascript, arrays, velo

Thank you for looking at thus question. It's driving me crazy.

I have 2 databases with various fields which are:

> **dataset = projectproducts**
>
> **field ID** = `product`  // matching ID in products dataset
>
> **field ID**  = `productQuantity`  // returns number

> **dataset = products**
>
> **field ID** = `_id`  // matching product field value in projectproducts
>
> **field ID** = `productPrice`  // returns number

I am trying to query the **projectproducts dataset** and retrieve the items from the `product` field (several hundred of them) and the quantity from the `productQuantity` field.

Then based on the `product` field (which is the **`ID`** of the item/row in the **products dataset**) query the products dataset and retrieve the result from `productPrice` field.

Then I'd like to multiply the

> `productQuantity` result **x** `productPrice` result

and **add all the values together** to retrieve a final amount.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about how it's different when datasets are involved but here is an approach which uses `wixData` directly

```js
import wixData from 'wix-data';

$w.onReady(async function () {
    const {items: projectproducts} = await wixData.query('projectproducts').find();
    const projectproductsQuery = wixData.query('products');
    projectproducts.forEach(pp => {
        projectproductsQuery.eq('_id', pp.product)
    })
    const {items: products} = await projectproductsQuery.find();
    const productsPrices = products.reduce((acc, current) => ({
        ...acc,
        [current._id]: current.price
    }), {});
    console.log({products, productsPrices, projectproducts});
    const sum = projectproducts.reduce((acc, current) => {
        return acc + productsPrices[current.product] * current.productQuantity;
    }, 0);
    console.log(sum);
});
```

Demo: https://moshef9.wixsite.com/agg-collections (Open the `console` for more information about the collections)